# splitting string values nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, scripting

I am trying to split my values from an array.

it looks like this:

```
[ 'xs', 'small', 'medium' ]
```

and I want to split them up so they show like this in my database:

```
xs small medium
```

I have this so far:

```
    const str = size;
    const words = str.split(',');                                  
       if (words.length > 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            console.log("Words: " + words[i])
         }
      }
```

but I get the error

```
TypeError: str.split is not a function
```

not sure why, thought this would work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.split()` is a function of `Strings`, not `Arrays`. I suppose you're trying o join them, right?

```js
const str = size;
let data = str.join(" ");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Well I want to I guess extract them out from the array and insert into my db table as `xs small medium` Instead of the array format. Basivally split the words up.

Comment: `data` is in `String` form. I guess you want to add them to DB one by one?